# Python: Replacing a String in a YAML file

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have this example YAML file:

```
---
test:
  name: "Tom"
  age: "5"
  version: "1.0"
```

How can I replace this YAML file to this:

---

```
test:
  name: "Max"
  age: "10"
  version: "2.2"
```

This is the way I open the file:

```
import yaml

with open("config.yml", 'r') as stream:
        print(yaml.load(stream))
```

But I have no idea, how to edit the YAML file now.

Comment: Please tell us what you already tried and what research you did before posting the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the fact that you use `PyYaml`, the appropriate way to do this is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import yaml

with open("testfile.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        loaded = yaml.load(stream)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)

# Modify the fields from the dict
loaded['test']['name'] = "Max"
loaded['test']['age'] = "10"
loaded['test']['version'] = "2.2"

# Save it again
with open("modified.yaml", 'w') as stream:
    try:
        yaml.dump(loaded, stream, default_flow_style=False)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

So you just load the yaml into a `dict` called `loaded`, you modify the values you need then you save it (overwriting the original file or not, your call). For a nested input you'd have a nested dict you'd have to modify. The `default_flow_style=False` parameter is necessary to produce the format you want (flow style), otherwise for nested collections it produces block style:

```
A: a
B: {C: c, D: d, E: e}
```

Cheers!

**Later edit**:

As Anthon pointed out, my answer has some flaws.

- It's better to use `safe_load` instead of `load` since the later is potentially dangerous.
- The output needs an directive end indicator (those three dashes at the beginning). To append them, we use `explicit_start=True` in the `dump` method (that should actually be `safe_dump`).
- Use maybe `ruamel.yaml` instead of `yaml`, if you want to generate a better output (although they are semantically the same)

See Anthon's answer for a more detailed information, since he's the author of the package.

Comment: You should not be using PyYAML's `load`, it is potentially unsafe. The format the OP wants is called block style not flow-style, you have those two terms confused. Also if you don't specify `default_flow_style` only the leaf nodes would be affected **not** all nested collections. Your output doesn't have the leading `directives end indicator`. -1 for the aforementioned errors in your answer, +1 for at least using the recommended extension for YAML files.

Comment: @Anthon Thanks for poiting those out. Is it okay to modify my answer and add some info about `ruamel.yaml` and `safe_load`? Also, I did not know about `explicit_start=True` parameter, I just found it in the documentation. *Edit*: I just saw you posted a more detailed answer.

Comment: Sure you can use that, it is probably better to update the answer to at least have the `safe_load` in there (for anyone using copy-and-paste), but fixing the other things would be good as well. My preference is not to use sections like `Later edit`, just try to keep a single coherent whole. The edit history is there in case anyone wants to know "how it used to be before improvements"

Answer (score 6):

If you read through the PyYAML documentation, you will see that it
tells you that using the `load()` function is potentially dangerous,
so the first thing to do (since you, and almost everybody else don't
need it), is not using that, but using `safe_load()` instead.

You should also change your input file to `config.yaml`, the
[recommended extension](https://yaml.org/faq.html) for YAML files has been `.yaml` since at 2006.

Knowing that, the way to change a `config.yaml` file using PyYAML:

```
import yaml

with open('config.yaml') as stream:
   data = yaml.safe_load(stream)

test = data['test']
test.update(dict(name="Tom", age="10", version="2.2"))

with open('output.yaml', 'wb') as stream:
   yaml.safe_dump(data, stream, default_flow_style=False, 
                  explicit_start=True, allow_unicode=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

This will get you an `output.yaml` that looks like:

```
---
test:
  age: '10'
  name: Tom
  version: '2.2'
```

The `default_flow_style` parameter is necessary to not get a JSON like
structure for your leaf node mapping. The `explicit_start` to get the
leading diretives end indicator (`---`), and I recommend to always use
`allow_unicode=True, encoding='utf-8'` (and open the file as binary)
in order not to run into surprises or problems when you change `name`
to `Björk Guðmundsdóttir`.

Now as you will notice, this doesn't generate the output that you want
(although semantically the same):

- single quotes instead of double quotes around the strings that could be interpreted as numbers
- no double quotes around `Tom`
- sorting of the keys of your mapping

If you had any comments in the YAML file, these would have been lost.

The better way to update YAML files is using `ruamel.yaml`
(disclaimer: I am the author of that package), which has some more
sany defaults than PyYAML, handles YAML 1.2 and doesn't drop comments
(if you would have them in your file):

```
import ruamel.yaml


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.explicit_start = True

with open('config.yaml') as stream:
   data = yaml.load(stream)

test = data['test']
test.update(dict(name="Tom", age="10", version="2.2"))

with open('output.yaml', 'wb') as stream:
    yaml.dump(data, stream)
```

with that your output file will be:

```
---
test:
  name: "Tom"
  age: "10"
  version: "2.2"
```

which is exactly what you wanted.